Is there any formula for solar sail velocity?
I'm interested in solar sail, and I've researched the velocity achieved by solar sail. If we have only 4 sail parameters, can we make a formula for solar sail velocity?

m:mass of sail, A:area of sail, r_1=initial distance from sun, R=reflectivity
And also we have to consider solar gravitational deceleration

Do https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4587/solar-sail-thrust-calculation or https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2997/can-i-derive-a-combined-equation-for-velocity-of-solar-sail help?  I think this question is a duplicate of one or the other
