# Thrust for solar sail equation derivation

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics, solar-sail

In the new SMAD (Chapter 18 Space Mission Engineering and Analysis) they have the equation for thrust of a solar sail and a reduced version. Variables are described in [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4587/12102).

I would like to reproduce this simplification. Can someone explain how they got from the first one to the simplified version? What numerical values (the *actual values too*, not only their descriptions) were likely to have been used to get the numerical value of $9.113 \times 10^{-6}$?

[image: Chapter 18 Space Mission Engineering and Analysis]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what each of the used variables mean?

Comment: Here's a clue for you: Get the value of speed of light in m/s, the value of the solar flux in W/(m*m) at 1 A.U., and the factor of 2, and see if you can come up with that magic number.  Then I bet you can figure the rest out.

Answer (score 4):

## Unit

When dealing with a magic number, it's important to know what its unit should be.

$$F=\frac{2RSA}{c}\sin^2\theta=9.113\times10^{-6}\frac{RA}{D^2}\sin^2\theta$$

- $F$ is a thrust (=Force) in Newton.
- $R$, $2$ and $\sin^2$ are unitless.
- $A$ is an area in $m^2$.
- It means that $\frac{S}{c}$ is a pressure in Pascal.

By simplifying $R$, $A$ and $\sin$, we get:

$$\frac{2S}{c}=9.113\times10^{-6}\frac{1}{D^2}$$

- $D$ is a distance in $\mathrm{AU}$
- It means that $9.113\times10^{-6}$ is a force in a non-conventional unit : $\mathrm{Pascal} * \mathrm{AU}^2$

## Value

This equation should be valid anywhere in the solar system. In particular, it should work on Earth ($D = 1 \mathrm{AU}$), where $S$ is the [solar constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant) : $1361 \mathrm{W/m²}$.

Using [qalculate](https://qalculate.github.io/) with $2*S/c$:

```
> 2 * 1361W/m² / c to Pa

  ((2 * (1361 * watt)) / (meter^2)) / speed_of_light = approx. 9.0796147 uPa
```

Close enough! It seems that $1366 \mathrm{W/m²}$ has been used to get $9.113\times10^{-6} \mathrm{Pa}$.

Using [inverse-square law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law), you get the desired equation.